# Taking different inputs from a file and distinguishing them

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, filereader

So I have a text file as so (not double spaced)

```
4
1 5 3 5 6 7 9
14
0 3 1 6 3
11
```

and I want to take the numbers as a test case value (first number only), sort status (can be 0/1), number of elements in an array, and the array elements themselves. Then I take more test arrays with the same information. However, with my code, I can't figure out how to add the numbers to an array.

```
    File file = new File("\\Users\\rike6\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\sample_in.txt");
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    
    int[] array = {};
    
    int testCase = scan.nextInt();
    int sortStatus = scan.nextInt();
    int arraySize = scan.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize - 1; i++)
        array[i] = scan.nextInt();
    int target = scan.nextInt();
```

Output:
Test case amount:4

Is This Array Sorted(1 for yes, 0 for no): Yes

Number of Elements in This Array: 5

Array Elements: { 3,5,6,7,9}

Target: 14

Is The Next Array Sorted: No

so on...

Comment: You need to size your array. e.g. `int[] array = new int[arraySize]`. Better yet, use an `ArrayList`

Comment: What do you mean by sort status?  You have shown the input.  Please show the expected output for that input.

Comment: I added an output. I just want to assign the inputs from the file to variables in my program.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you read in an array.  In this case, the data is in a string of values you posted (except for 11 which was not followed by any subsequent data).  The string is read just like a file would be.

```
String data = "4 1 5 3 5 6 7 9 14 0 3 1 6 3";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(data);

while (scan.hasNext()) {
    int testCase = scan.nextInt();
    int sortStatus = scan.nextInt();
    int arraySize = scan.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[arraySize];
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    
    System.out.printf("testCase = %d, sortStatus = %d, arraysSize = %d, array=%s%n",
            testCase, sortStatus, arraySize, Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

prints

```
testCase = 4, sortStatus = 1, arraysSize = 5, array=[3, 5, 6, 7, 9]
testCase = 14, sortStatus = 0, arraysSize = 3, array=[1, 6, 3]
```

Comment: I would appreciate some feedback on this.